# AS2 : right click detection

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, right-click

I have a problem of right click detection in AS2. I develop games and everything is frozen when the user right clicks. I want to avoid or to detect that.

I've spent a lot of time searching and the code I found doesn't work.
The more common script I found is :

```
onEnterFrame = function () {
    if (Key.isDown(2) || ASnative(800, 2)(2)) trace("right click");
}
```

It seems that it used to work but no more (even on MAC or on PC).

Does someone have a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution : adding a function call in the ContextMenu creation.

```
function onRightClick() {
    // Code here
}
// The detection is made by the function call in the brackets
var myMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(onRightClick);
_root.menu = myMenu;
```

Comment: you can accept this answer if it answered your question, and it is absolutely fine to answer your own questions.